# How to merge two columns into one column where they have highest ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I run a Carrom club where I pair two players for each game and then record the game results in `GamesTable`. A player's ID can appear in `Player1ID` column or in `Player2ID` column depending on who wins the toss. The `GamesTable` table looks like this:

```
| GameID | Player1ID | Player2ID | Player1RatingAfterGame | Player2RatingAfterGame |
|--------|-----------|-----------|------------------------|------------------------|
| 5579   | 33        | 166       | 1020                   | 980                    |
| 5580   | 155       | 67        | 980                    | 1020                   |
| 5581   | 66        | 57        | 980                    | 1020                   |
| 5582   | 29        | 160       | 1020                   | 980                    |
| 5583   | 167       | 166       | 1019                   | 961                    |
| 5584   | 167       | 29        | 1004                   | 1035                   |
| 5585   | 67        | 155       | 1033                   | 962                    |
```

I am trying to run a query to generate a leaderboard wherein a player's rating from his 'latest game' is taken. High rated players get to the top of the leaderboard. ('Latest game' is defined by the GameID. The most recent game has higher GameID.)

My aim is to get an output like this:

```
| Rank | PlayerID | PlayerLatestRating |
|------|----------|--------------------|
| 1    | 67       | 1033               |
| 2    | 33       | 1020               |
| 3    | 66       | 980                |
| 4    | 155      | 962                |
| 5    | 166      | 961                |
```

It would have been easier to run a query if playerIDs were in a single column. But in my case the playerIDs appear in both columns. How do I bring them down into a single column and get their latest rating?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not normalise the GamesTable slightly `(GameId, PlayerId, Rating)`? You could create a composite `UNIQUE KEY` on `(GameId, PlayerId)` to prevent the same PlayerId from featuring more than once in a single game. As far as maximum number of players per game are concerned, it can be taken care of by `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER`s, if absolutely necessary.

Comment: The GamesTable has grown very bulky. Wonder I may break all my code if I change its structure at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL` to bring the two player into single set of columns and filter using a correlated query for the latest game.

```
set @rnk := 0;

select @rnk := @rnk + 1 as rnk, t.*
from (
    select gameid, player1id as playerid, player1ratingaftergame as rating
    from gamestable
    union all
    select gameid, player2id, player2ratingaftergame
    from gamestable
    ) t
where gameid = (select max(gameid)
                from gamestable g
                where t.playerid in (g.player1id, g.player2id)
                )
order by rating desc;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/UDGEN94905)

Answer (score 0):

**Try RENAME and UNION Clause to Merge**

```
SELECT @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS Rank, PlayerID, PlayerLatestRating FROM (
    SELECT Player1ID as PlayerID, Player1RatingAfterGame as PlayerLatestRating FROM GamesTable
    UNION
    SELECT Player2ID as PlayerID, Player2RatingAfterGame as PlayerLatestRating FROM GamesTable
) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY Rank ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa3efa/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can get latest game id per player with the following query:

```
SELECT a.pid, max(a.gid)
FROM (
    SELECT player1ID as pid, MAX(gameID) as gid
    FROM GamesTable
    GROUP BY Player1ID

    UNION 

    SELECT player2ID as pid, MAX(gameID) as gid
    FROM GamesTable
    GROUP BY Player2ID
 ) a;
```

Once you get these ids, you can write a `SELECT` with `CASE` statement to get the score, depending on whether pid is player1 or player2 in that game, and sort it in descending order.